# Unable to log in with Google account to the Stack Overflow iOS app (Request failed)

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, ios-app

I just downloaded the Stack Overflow iOS app and when I try to log on with my Google account (which I use on the website) I get the following error:

> REQUEST FAILED
>
> Could not perform this request with your account. Please try logging back in. If this persists, let us know on meta.

I did a search for the error, but I didn’t find anything.

I am running iOS 11.4.1 on an iPhone 7.

Any thoughts?

> UPDATE
>
> I just tested on an iPad mini with iOS 11.3. The same result.
>
> UPDATE 2
>
> I added a new login (username/password) to my account and I am able to log in to the app with that one. Logging in with my Google account still does not work.

[image]

Comment: I just tried with my Google account on iOS 11.4.1 on an iPhone SE and I could log in fine. Probably means it’s something specific to your account.

Comment: I added a new login to my account (email / password) and with this one I can log in. So I assume it’s related to my Google account. When I get home from my holidays, I’ll use fiddler to see what response the authentication generates.

Comment: Still an issue. Tried logging out of all devices but no luck. Did you ever find a solution? @SvenDeBont

Comment: Still the same issue (both on the StackExchange and StackOverflow app).

Comment: Same probleme here - IOS12. Works fine with IOS9/IPhone4S.

Comment: Happened to me when I replaced my phone. Maybe it's time to change my login method.

Comment: This is happening on the stack exchange app as well.

Comment: Happening on android application as well: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376640/656600. Why this have not been taken into account 4 months?

Comment: The mobile app development team is essentially disbanded at this point, so I don't think there is going to be a timeline on fixing this issue. See [Stop advertising the SE app on the mobile site](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/307065) and [Why has Stack Exchange stopped working on the Android app?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/272419)

Comment: I'm encountering this issue currently on ipad. I am able to login and view my account but not post. I followed the advice to log out and log back in and it logged back in but it still would not let me post. I am able to post when using a laptop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cross-posted with the Android bug.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376116/cannot-sign-in-with-google-error-expanding-fields-parameter-cannot-find-matc/377266#377266)

This is fixed.

When the Android and iOS apps perform a Google login, we get back an access_token or id_token from Google that we then use to retrieve the email address and validate that the token is associate with one of our apps. To do this, we hit Google's `tokeninfo` endpoint, checking the `email` and `audience`/`aud` fields.  According to their documentation and even their API explorer, you should be able to pass `fields=email,audience` as a parameter to limit the fields that are returned.

At some point, however, that broke (as demonstrated by executing the [this request](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/oauth2/oauth2/v2/oauth2.tokeninfo?fields=audience%252Cemail&_h=1&)).  Fortunately, by just dropping the `fields` parameter, we can get Google to send back all of the fields and we can just read the two we care about.

---

I should add, you can also get this error if no email address is associated with your Google account or if you disable the email permission during authentication (though I'm not sure this is possible).  Since you got the error on multiple devices, well before everyone experienced it on November 4, I suspect this may be the case.

Comment: Just logged out of the app and signed in with my google account. Indeed fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed **some** factors among others that most times result to this;

- When one changes his device or try to login with a new device, he sometimes stumble on this error.
- Possible error in connection between your Google app and the iOS app.

I will suggest that you try the following:

- You might want to check your [Google activities](https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity) and be sure there's no strange activity going on from your account.
- You can also try the listed [solution](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257) suggested by google though on a different issue.
- Try a new login to your account from a computer directly not from an app. So that you can be sure it has nothing to do with your Google account.
- Try update your iOS version.

**Updated**

I will suggest you also get to read more from this [stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272419/367834) answer and [Why has Stack Exchange stopped working on the Android app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307065/stop-advertising-the-se-app-on-the-mobile-site) as mentioned by @Martijn Pieters in the comment.

I hope this might help out.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and what I figured out is that Google refuses to work within the app scope. Browsers are fine.