# Cannot sign in with Google: Error expanding 'fields' parameter. Cannot find matching fields for path 'email'

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, login

I have a new Android smartphone and here's what I get when trying to login with Google:

[image]

Comment: What phone is this? What's the OS version?

Comment: S9, Android 8.0.0

Comment: The problem is you are using an application that was left behind. I'm amazed it doesn't even read "Stack Exchange".

Comment: what do you mean with "left behind" - should I get an iPhone instead?

Comment: Nah, the Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow apps development stopped like a year ago or something like that

Comment: Re mobile app dev having ended: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299862/are-more-mobile-app-review-or-moderation-features-coming/300389#300389

Comment: Does anyone know if we can enable push notifications for new item in our inbox somehow without the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed.

When the Android and iOS apps perform a Google login, we get back an access_token or id_token that from Google that we then use to retrieve the email address and validate that the token is associate with one of our apps.  To do this, we hit Google's `tokeninfo` endpoint, checking the `email` and `audience`/`aud` fields.  Accoring to their documentation and even their API explorer, you should be able to pass `fields=email,audience` as a parameter to limit the fields that are returned.

At some point, however, that broke (as demonstrated by executing the [this request](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/oauth2/oauth2/v2/oauth2.tokeninfo?fields=audience%252Cemail&_h=1&)).  Fortunately, by just dropping the `fields` parameter, we can get Google to send back all of the fields and we can just read the two we care about.