# How do I log in to the Stack Overflow web version via a Google OAuth Android device with the Stack Overflow app installed?

Tags: bug

My Android device has the Stack Overflow app installed. It is a normal situation that one opens Stack Overflow posts(s) via the Chrome app.

When logging in via Google OAuth, a new tab is opened, then after authentication, the browser will open the app. The browser tab keeps un-logged in.

While the expected behavior is closing the authentication tab and my account gets logged in. Or at least, after the app opens (after the user authenticates their Google account), it should open the question being opened in the browser.

Comment: Duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376116/cannot-sign-in-with-google-error-expanding-fields-parameter-cannot-find-matc?

Comment: No. I have read it. It is different. I have same problem with the OP though. It looks like the mobile dev has been stopped for loong time. I jave uninstalled thr app and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/390254

The mobile app dev has been stopped a long time ago. After uninstalling the mobile app, I can login normally.