# Unable to login to the SO iOS app with Google

Tags: support, ios-app, stack-overflow-app

My SO account is linked to my Google account. I’ve purchased a new phone and I’m unable to login to the SO iOS app. Keep receiving an error. I am able to login through Safari. Any work around for this?

**Error**:

[image]

**Device**:

iPhone XR
iOS 12.1

Comment: Same issue as [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372621/unable-to-log-in-with-google-account-to-the-stack-overflow-ios-app-request-fail)?

Comment: @yivi correct. I’ve marked this a a dupe. Doesn’t look like the app is still being supported I guess.

Comment: Looks that way. I only keep it for the notifications, but even for that you'd need to log-in anyway...

Comment: @yivi same. The notifications were really nice.