# Having trouble logging in to the iOS app with my account

Tags: support, stack-overflow-app, bug-reporting-process, ios

I am trying to sign into my Stack Overflow account on my phone, but it keeps telling me 'user does not exist'.

I have double, triple, and quadruple checked my log in credentials, but the problem persists.

Comment: Is it this problem: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372621/unable-to-log-in-with-google-account-to-the-stack-overflow-ios-app-request-fail ?

Answer (score 3):

They have closed down the Mobile Version for it, I guess. It is not even available on App stores. They still have kept Stack Exchange though which contains support for all websites in the network.

Even I faced a similar issue after trying to re-login. I checked and found they removed it.

Comment: I see. That explains it.